# Overriding __contains__ method of dict breaks after first key:value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, fuzzywuzzy

My use-case with an example:

```py
m = Mapping()

m["John Doe"] = "PERSON"
m["Google"] = "ORG"
```

I want to be able to **NOT** insert entities like "John", "Mr. John" or "Mr. Doe" since a similar entity ("John Doe") exists in the mapping.

Here is my implementation of Mapping class (please check **contains**):

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

class Mapping(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.__dict__[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__dict__[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__dict__)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.__dict__[key]

    def clear(self):
        return self.__dict__.clear()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def has_key(self, k):
        return k in self.__dict__

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__dict__.update(*args, **kwargs)

    def keys(self):
        return self.__dict__.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self.__dict__.values()

    def items(self):
        return self.__dict__.items()

    def pop(self, *args):
        return self.__dict__.pop(*args)

    def __cmp__(self, dict_):
        return self.__cmp__(self.__dict__, dict_)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        for key in self.__dict__.keys():
# if incoming token is a partial or complete match of an existing token in the mapping
            if fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio(item, key) == 100: 
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__dict__)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(repr(self.__dict__))
```

This breaks my example:

```py
"John" in m # returns True as expected
"Goo" in m # returns False ?

fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio("Goo", "Google") # returns 100
fuzz.partial_token_set_ratio("John", "John Doe") # returns 100
```

Why does this break after the first key?

Comment: The whole point of extending `dict` is that you don't have to copy and paste all the methods to have them work.

Comment: `__dict__` is not what you think it is. Look at `m.__dict__` to see what I mean.

Comment: Why are you doing things this way? It makes no sense. Now, your `Mapping` object carries around *two dicts*, the object itself (which is a `dict`), **and** a `__dict__` dict, which is it's namespace.

Comment: Also, this isn't working because your `__contains__` method **always returns on the first iteration**. But this all seems rather misguided.

Comment: I want to be able to disambiguate multiple variations of names and merge into one key.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a somewhat simpler problem.  Suppose you want dictionary `D` to internally use keys like `"John Doe"`, but you want it to still be able to have `D["Mr. John Doe"]` return the same thing as `D["John Doe"]`.

To do this, I would write a function that converts any acceptable name (like "Mr. John Doe") to its canonical version.

```py
def canonical_version_of(name: str) -> str:
    return name.removeprefix('Mr. ')  # Requires Python 3.9+
```

Then you'll need to create some sort of custom dictionary subclass that will internally employ canonical versions of names.  There are 4 main options for this:

1. You can subclass `dict` directly, and then use calls to `super()` to access the default dict functionality.  This requires overriding virtually all of the default `dict.__dunder__` methods, since most of them are hard-wired to do things with keys without canonicalizing them first.  The original post attempted to follow this model, but did not use `super()` to access the dict's internal content, so wouldn't work as expected.
2. You can write a container class with its own `.data` attribute to store the canonical version of the dictionary, and implement all the relevant `__dunder__` methods in it.  This ends up very similar to approach #1, except rather than calling `super()` to access basic dict functionality, you would apply that functionality to `.data`.
3. You can subclass the Abstract Base Class `MutableMapping`, again storing the canonical version of the dict in a `.data` attribute.  This lets you define fewer of the `__dunder__` methods, while it automatically infers the rest. So generally this is preferable to 1 and 2.
4. You can use import `UserDict` from `collections` and subclass it.  This automatically defines default dictionary-like behavior for all the relevant methods, storing the underlying dict in a `.data` attribute.  In general this will probably be the easiest approach, minimizing the number of `__dunder__` methods you'll need to override, and accessing `.data` is often a bit more intuitive than making calls to `super()`.

Whichever of the above approaches you choose, you'll need to write some `__dunder__` methods (at least `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `__contains__`) to convert each given key to its canonical version before reading or writing to the dictionary.  Working with approach #4, here's a partial example, though I haven't gone through the full list of `__dunder__` methods to check whether there are more you'd need to canonicalize.

```py
from collections import UserDict

class CanonicalDict(UserDict):
    """Like an ordinary dict, except canonical_version_of(key) is always
       used in place of ordinary keys."""

    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        return self.data[canonical_version_of(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value): 
        self.data[canonical_version_of(key)] = value
    
    def __contains__(self, key): 
        return canonical_version_of(key) in self.data
```

This approach can easily be generalized changing `canonical_version_of` to canonicalize names in other ways, e.g. to handle "Doe, John" or "JOHN DOE" or "Doe, John Doe".  This would give you *most* of what you asked for in the original post.

However, this approach does require that any given key be rich enough in information to generate the canonical version of the name, so e.g., if the internal `.data` will store Mr. Doe's entry under `John Doe` then the key would need to somehow include both 'John' and 'Doe' in it.  This would get in the way of the original post's desire to be able to use 'Mr. Doe' or 'John' as keys for accessing the dictionary.

To get something like this, you could rewrite `canonical_version_of` to first look for a close-enough match among the dictionary's existing keys, and if it can't find one, then to return the key as given.  Since this version of `canonical_version_of` requires a dictionary to look in, I would make it a method of your custom `CanonicalDict` class, and then have other methods like `__getitem__` call it as `self.canonical_version_of(key)`.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process

class CanonicalDict(UserDict):
    def canonical_version_of(self, name:str) -> str:
        """Returns the best match for name among this CanonicalDict's keys if 
           that match scores at least 90%.  Otherwise returns name."""
        if not self.data: return name  # handle case where this dict is empty
        candidate, score = process.ExtractOne(name, self.data.keys())
        if score >= 90: return candidate
        return name

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[self.canonical_version_of(key)]

    # ... and similarly for other __dunder__ methods...
```

This approach basically adopts whatever name is initially used for an individual as that individual's "canonical name" and then keeps using that name internally for any other close-enough name, allowing new canonical names to be coined only when they are distinct-enough from all existing ones.

I would use a scheme like this only in cases where I'm sure that there just a few keys to be stored in the dictionary (ideally ones that I could pre-seed with "good" canonical names) and these keys are all far apart from each other.  E.g., this might be a fine approach to use to help people look up entries in an in-game encyclopedia with keys created by you. But if your dictionary might contain keys with similar or overlapping names, then the results of this sort of fuzzy-matching approach could be quite unpredictable and highly dependent upon the order of key storage.  E.g., if you store John Doe's initial entry under "John Doe", then (depending upon how close of a match you demand) all future references to either "John" or "Doe" might be redirected to this existing entry.  But if you store his initial entry under "Mr. Doe" and then later try to look up "John" it probably wouldn't recognize those as being close enough to match.  So be warned that this approach could be quite finicky and not necessarily a good idea!  But you asked...